# How to implement temporary function "memoization"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memoization

The function to be memoized is not "pure" (its return value may change in the future) so I cannot use the [memoize](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) decoration.
Moreover, I will need the list of values it was called on.

What I do is

```
def f(...):
    cache = {}
    for ...:
        try:
            x = cache[k]
        except KeyError:
            x = cache[k] = expensive(k)
        # use x here
    for x in cache.itervalues():
        cleanup(x)
```

I wonder if this is the "pythonic" way to express the paradigm.

E.g., I can save 3 lines by writing

```
def f(...):
    cache = {}
    for ...:
        x = cache[k] = cache.get(k) or expensive(k)
        # use x here
    for x in cache.itervalues():
        cleanup(x)
```

Instead (assume that `None`, `0`, `""`, `[]`, `{}` and other false values are not possible return values of `expensive`).

Does this look better?

Comment: @timgeb: first, I use python 2, not python 3. Second, the caching must be _local_ to my function `f`.

Comment: So to be clear, each `cache` may only live as long as its function call is going on?

Comment: @timgeb: yes, local only

Comment: @glibdud: whatever you want to call it. the question is about style.

Comment: Note that `cache.get(k)` may return other falsy values than `None` such as `''`, `0`, `[]`. After some consideration, I think the try/except approach is fine. You could also use `if k in cache` instead.

Comment: @timgeb, yes, `expensive` always returns true

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the first way you've done it. Don't sacrifice readability to eliminate a few lines... also Try/Except is quite fast generally, so you're not losing out on performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd stick with the `try`/`except` version, since baking in assumptions about the return value of `expensive` being truthy is a bad idea for generalizability (and performance-wise, as an implementation detail, `d[k]` is faster than `d.get(k)` on CPython, and the cost of the exception is generally comparable to the cost of the conditional check, not to mention all of that is likely noise next to the `expensive` function). I would make one tweak though, to uniquify the result when two threads race, and both end up computing the expensive result, to avoid them each receiving their own (possibly expensive) copy of the result. Change the line in the `except KeyError` handler from:

```
x = cache[k] = expensive(k)
```

to:

```
x = cache.setdefault(k, expensive(k))
```

Doing it this way, if two threads both begin computing `expensive` at the same time, the first to complete it will store the cached value, the second will promptly throw away its own result in favor of the cached value stored by the first. If the result is only expensive to compute, not expensive in memory or other resource costs per-instance, this doesn't hurt, and if it is expensive in other ways, this quickly eliminates the duplicated value.

It's not actually 100% thread-safe on CPython unless `k` is a C-level built-in (because in theory, there are some race conditions `setdefault` could trigger in truly pathological conditions when executing a Python level `__eq__` function for collision resolution), but the worst case scenario there is simply that the deduplication doesn't work.

If you don't like all that kruft rolled into the function itself, a good way to factor it out is to roll your own `dict` subclass that follows the general pattern of `collections.defaultdict` (but uses the key as part of computing the default value). It's not that hard, thanks to the `__missing__` hook `dict` provides:

```
# Easiest to let defaultdict define the alternate constructor and attribute name
from collections import defaultdict

class CacheDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        # Roughly the same implementation as defaultdict's default
        # __missing__, but passing the key as the argument to the factory function
        return self.setdefault(key, self.default_factory(key))
```

Having written that class, you can write your function with far less cache related kruft:

```
def f(...):
    cacheorcompute = CacheDict(expensive)
    for ...:
        x = cacheorcompute[k]
        # use x here
    for x in cacheorcompute.itervalues():
        cleanup(x)
```

Comment: I love your CacheDict suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by ShadowRanger is probably what you're looking for, but I would also consider an additional separation of concerns by doing setup and cleanup tasks in one place, and punting the work utilizing `x`s out elsewhere using [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def xs_manager(...):
    """Manages setup/teardown of cache of x's"""
    # setup
    cache = {}
    def gencache():
        """Inner generator for passing each x outside"""
        for ...:
            try:
                x = cache[k]
            except KeyError:
                x = cache[k] = expensive(k)
            yield x
    yield gencache()
    # external use of x's occurs here
    # teardown
    for x in cache.itervalues():
        cleanup(x)

def f(...):
    with xs_manager(...) as xvaluecache:
        for x in xvaluecache:
            # use x here
```

Now you can do this of course:

```
>>> f(...)
```

..however, now that we've separated out the setup/teardown we can come back to this code later if we want to do other tasks with `x`s (other than `f`) that we may not have considered previously, including `g(x)` and `h(x)`:

```
>>> with xs_manager(...) as xvaluecache:
...    for x in xvaluecache:
...        g(x)
...        h(x)
```

So this is a bit more code, but it sets you up for more possibilities down the line.